# Vue2 dynamic v-model for a group

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, v-model

I am working on a housing form and I am stuck somewhere and I am hoping someone give me a solution to my problem.

So, when you select in a form that your house have 2 floors, then you get to write each floor how many rooms, toilets, balcony etc has..

My issue is to "group" these answers somehow that I could send it to my backend and "read" those answers.

so this is what I did so far:

```
data() {
  return {
    flooroptions: [
      {
        name: 'Rooms',
        id: '1',
      },
      {
        name: 'Balcony',
        id: '2',
      },
      {
        name: 'Toilets',
        id: '3',
      },
    ],
    floors: '',
    floor1: [],
  },
}
```

and if I loop through like this:

```
<div class="" v-for="(opt, index) in flooroptions">
  <input type="number" name="" value="" v-model="floor1[index]">
</div>
```

I can see my data using floor1:

```
{{ floor1 }}
```

But if in the form someone selects that 1st floor has 2 rooms and does not add any other input than I get to floor1 only 2

How would be better approach for this type of problem ??

PS. Everyfloor will have this flooroptions loop and they can input number of each option for each floor, and I want to be able to read that number correctly..

Comment: Maybe it will be easier for you now and in the long run if you just merge floor options in the floor record? Unless you have or anticipate some other floor-based business logic?

Comment: @NickM well I was thinking to merge that, to do some "duplicate" text but I was just wondering if there is any other way around because otherwise I could do something like floor1rooms:, floor1bathrooms etc.. and get their value...

Comment: Why not floors = [ { name: “first floor”, bathrooms: 1, balconies: 2, rooms:5,... },... ] and then it’s all easier to iterate with <dir v-for=floor in floors> {{floor.bathrooms...</div>

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, I would...

```
data() {
  return {
    flooroptions: [
    {
      name: 'Rooms',
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      name: 'Balcony',
      id: '2',
    },
    {
      name: 'Toilets',
      id: '3',
    },
    ],
    numFloors: 2,
    floorData: [
      {'Rooms':0, 'Balcony':0, 'Toilets':2},
      {'Rooms':2, 'Balcony':1, 'Toilets':0}
    ],
  },
}
```

and loop through like this:

```
<div v-for="f in numFloors">
  <div class="" v-for="opt in flooroptions">
    <input type="number" name="" value="" v-model="floorData[f][opt.name]">
  </div>
</div>
```

or... if you want to pass less data and the id's are know on the backen

```
data() {
  return {
    flooroptions: {
      1: {
        name: 'Rooms'
      },
      2: {
        name: 'Balcony'
      },
      3: {
        name: 'Toilets'
      },
    },
    numFloors: 2,
    floorData: [
      {1:0, 2:0, 3:2},
      {1:2, 2:1, 3:0}
    ],
  },
}
```

and loop through like this:

```
<div v-for="f in numFloors">
  <div class="" v-for="(opt, i) in flooroptions">
    <input type="number" name="" value="" v-model="floorData[f][i]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thnx for your time, I did exactly what you suggested but I could not make it work. Here take a look.. https://jsfiddle.net/g3o7ysak/

Comment: I didn't realize you're using **vuejs 1.0**. The `(opt, i)` should be `(i, opt)` for it to work for